# Access Avro backed Hcatalog Table with Pig

Tags: apache-pig, avro, hcatalog

I created an Avro backed Table in Hcatalog that can be accessed through Hive or Pig.

In Pig i try to access this / load this table using HcatLoader.

Once i load it, and i describe am able to see the avro schema.

However when i DUMP out the values are not coming up and instead blanks are coming up.

For example

```
A = LOAD 'AvroTable' using HcatLoader;
B = FOREACH A generate x,y,z
DUMP B;
```

The output is (,,,2014,05) where 2014 and 05 are my partitions.

Just want to check am i missing anything here ? Am fairly new to trying out these, so any pointers will help me make progress.